# How to change the width of the PlaceHolderLeftNavBar to be longer without editing the master page?

Tags: 2007

The PlaceHolderLeftNavBar that I am referring to is as follows:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar">
```

I wish to change the width without editing the master page. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the scope of your change is.

If you only need to widen it on one (or a few) pages you can apply custom CSS to the page through the Look and Feel section of the site settings.

http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2010/05/using-themes-and-css-with-sharepoint-2010/

(Scroll down until after the themes)

If you want it wider on all pages, that's a master page thing.

The CSS class of the Left Navbar after it renders is #s4-leftpanel. Most of the base classes are listed on Erik Swenson's blog here:

http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-2010-base-css-classes.html

Comment: The first link that you provided require the use of the master page thing. I need a simple solution that only widen one (or a few) pages only probably using CSS or others.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I copied the wrong link over after I Googled your question for you. Let me edit to a correct one.

Comment: It's for 2010, but the Look and Feel setting is the same in 2007. I've done this in 2010 master pages no problem, never done it through an override.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a Content Editor WebPart or Simple Form WebPart (either one will work) to the page, open the WebPart properties, mark the WebPart as hidden and add the below CSS code to the HTML source view:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-quicklaunchouter
{
    width: 200px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I tested but seems like the PlaceHolderLeftNavBar width had not change at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: I also tried changing your `.ms-quicklaunchouter` to `PlaceHolderLeftNavBar` and also to `#PlaceHolderLeftNavBar` but it fail to increase the width of PlaceHolderLeftNavBar

Comment: `PlaceHolderLeftNavBar` is an ASP.NET/SharePoint placeholder which cannot be manipulated with CSS, hence I proposed to use the CSS class `ms-quicklaunchouter` which is rendered by this placeholder in SharePoint 2007.

Comment: yes, I did tried your `.ms-quicklaunchouter` but seem that it just could not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you really using SharePoint 2007? Please update your question with more code of your current masterpage.

Comment: Yes, definitely I am using SharePoint 2007. However, I cannot access the masterpage as I do not have the permission to access the top of the root site. Are there other ways to get that root masterpage?